# Angular Material Dropdown: object value with binding, initial (default) value not showing

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular2-template

Have a simple dropdown menu, populated with user objects:

```js
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>User</mat-label>
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="userSelected" id="user">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user">
              {{user.id}} {{user.name}}
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

The objects user and userSelected are simple User-objects, holding an ID and name field:

```js
  users: User[] = [
    {
      id: 'k2l13',
      name: 'SomeName'
    },
    {
      id: 'l3213',
      name: 'AnotherName'
    },
    {
      id: '23p13',
      name: 'OneMore'
    },
  ];
  
  userSelected: User = {
    id: 'k2l13',
    name: 'SomeName'
  },
```

The above solution will not show the userSelected as default user when the dropdown menu is displayed. However, the object corretly binds on value changes.

How can an object be bound to the dropdown AND be displayed initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior since `userSellected` and `users[0]` don't share the same reference (just as the result of `{} == {}` statement is false).

 Consider applying the the below change so `userSellected` would refer to an existing item within the array:

```js
userSelected: User = this.users[0];
```